# count number of lines a file has in ColdFusion

Tags: file-io, coldfusion

I'm keeping some basic info written in a file, but 99% of the time, I just need to count the number of lines there are as efficiently as it is reasonably possible.

is there a way to get the row? or do I need to loop through the file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the file and treat it as a list delimited by CR/LF characters. The [`listLen()`](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ListLen) will be the number of lines in the file. Depending on whether you want to count empty lines, you might need to use the `includeEmptyValues` option.

Comment: Wow, that is much faster(usable) compared to looping. Thanks Adam.

Comment: Not all files contain CR characters. If empty lines are counted then just using `ListLen(content,chr(10),true)` will work regardless of possible CRs.

Comment: It'll "work" sure (constrained my available memory). But you're probably better reading the file line-by-line, and counting the iterations until EOF for large files.